# the values field is required

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

**Detail:** I am trying to set up a simple get/post method inside asp.net controller and using postman to set if its set up correctly. I have looked for similar question on stackoverflow and they did not fixed my issue

**Error:**  My Get method works fine but my post method giving an following error. Please see below postman:

**debug:** if I add a break line inside post method. it is never reaching to that break line

[image]

**Code in asp.net**

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class CoursesTakenController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
       return new string[] {"value", "value" }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public Task<ActionResult<string>> Post([FromBody] string values)
    {
        return Ok(values);
    }
}
```

**I also tried this:** but doesnt work

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] string values)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are posting a json object while the method expects a string. `System.Text.Json` (default json serializer used by ASP.NET Core) is pretty restrictive in [`JsonTokenType`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsontokentype?view=net-7.0) handling, so either post a string i.e. just `"RandomText"` (or encoded into string json object - `{\"values\":\"asdasdasd\"}`) or change action to accept an object:

```cs
public class Tmp
{
    public required string Values { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<string>> Post([FromBody] Tmp values)
{
   ...
}
```